# Uploadify uploads pictures and nothing else

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, uploadify

I would like to use uploadify for other file types than images but I just cant get it work. It uploads any type of image with no problem. When i try to upload anything else the indicator shows 100% but there are no files to find in the upload folder (only the pictures).

The index.php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php $timestamp = time();?>
    $(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                            'checkExisting' : '/Bcp/uploadify/check-exists.php',
            'formData'     : {
                'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
            },
            'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
            'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',
                            'fileSizeLimit' : '50000KB',
                            'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png; *.png; *.mp3',
                            'fileTypeDesc' : 'Images and music'

        });
    });
</script>
```

The uploadify.php file:

```
$targetFolder = '/bcp/uploadify/uploads_pics'; // Relative to the root

$verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
$targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

// Validate the file type
$fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png', 'mp3'); // File extensions
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    echo '1';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid file type.';
}
```

}

Summary

Uploads images - yes, no problem

Uploads anything else - NO, why and how to get it work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

These two sections restrict uploads to images (and mp3s). They're likely your problem, and should be easy to strip out.

```
'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png; *.png; *.mp3',
```

and:

```
$fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png', 'mp3'); // File extensions
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    echo '1';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid file type.';
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know, the thing is it won't upload the mp3s... It does upload pictures (*.gif; *.jpg; *.png; *.png;) but totally ignores the mp3 files. When uploading the indicator shows 100% but it doesnt show it in the upload folder.